# Mapreduce failures log Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, hadoopy

Where can i find a log which contains information about failure of mapreduce jobs? If something goes wrong I just get an error exit with status 1. I am running Hadoop 2.4.1 and using Hadoopy for mapreduce jobs.

Comment: It depends on where you set your hadoop mapred log files in mapred-site.xml or if you are using YARN that it should be pointed it out in your yarn-site.xml. I usually set the log into /var/log/ along with other system log files.

Comment: would you mid to copy me your mapred-site and yarn-site? what is the default directory and what is the name of the log?

Comment: Try to read the [official documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/). Every Hadoop Developer went this way.

Answer (score 0):

By default logs will be save in /var/log. As discussed earlier the logs can be pointed to in configuration files available in /etc/hadoop/conf directory.